# get distinct item in List with highest value in property

Tags: c#, linq, list, iequalitycomparer

I have an object AppDetail containing 2 string properties, a name, and a version string (e.g. "1.0.0")

Given a List< AppDetail > that contains duplicates of the same name but different version strings, how do I create a List with unique names, and highest versions?

e.g. from these 2 items in the initial list

```
"name", "1.0.1"
"name", "1.1.0"
```

I want the unique items list to contain only the second item, since it has the highest version.

To compare versions I need to create an IComparer that creates Version objects and then to use the version.CompareTo(version) method. But thats not useful, since the [List.Distinct overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049) only accepts IEqualityComparer, not IComparer.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense that `List.Distinct()` doesn't accept an `IComparer`, since determining if two items are distinct does not *require* knowing if one item would precede another (or visa versa,) which is the purpose of the `IComparer` interface. Rather, all that is needed is to know whether or not two items are *equal*, which is exactly why `IEqualityComparer` exists.

You don't need to implement either, though. You can create a query that selects the appropriate items, by first grouping all the items by name, and then selecting only the highest version number from each group:

```
var namesWithHighestVersion = 
    appDetailList
        .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
        .Select(x => new AppDetail { 
                         Name = x.Key,
                         Version = x.Max(x => new Version(x.Version)).ToString()
                        })
        .ToList();
```

Note that this creates a new list, rather than updating the old list.

Also, you could simplify everything somewhat by making the original type use a `Version`, instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

simple query shown in pretty sql:

```
var aDetail  =  from a in appdetail
                group a by a.name into aGroup
                orderby a.version descending
                select new 
                    {name = aGroup.name, 
                     version = aGroup.Max(version)}.ToList();
```

The grouping will naturally make the query distinct

Sorry about earlier in using MaxBy, including the following project found here: **["more linq"](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)** made me think of MaxBy instinctively.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is similar to dlev's answer, however, it will return the instance of the one with the highest version, instead of creating a new instance with the same values.

```
var namesWithHighestVersion = 
    appDetailList
        .GroupBy(a => a.Name)
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(a => a.Version).First())
        .ToList();
```

Comment: This is definitely similar, but wrong in one key way: calling `OrderByDescending()` with a `string` argument will order the items lexicographically, which could be wrong when dealing with version numbers (e.g. 2.2 > 2.10 when both are considered a strings.)